# Introduction de la lettre « w » dans la langue française

Tags: orthographe, histoire, alphabet

On apprend tôt ou tard que  w n'est pas une lettre du véritable alphabet latin.

- À quelle époque remonte son introduction dans l'alphabet?
- À quelle langue l'emprunt a-t-il été fait? A-t-il été fait à l'allemand ou à l'anglais?
- Quelle est a été la nécessité de cette inclusion? Est-ce que w aurait remplacé une orthographe jugée indésirable dans des mots empruntés et francisés?

Comment: C'est quoi que vous appelez "**Véritable** alphabet latin" ?

Comment: @aCOSwt L'alphabet qu'a connu Caesar…

Comment: The English Wikipedia has some info regarding this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W), as well as some sources to go to. I won't take the time to compose an answer on this, since I know how wasted is the time we spend trying to help each other out, but have a look anyway, it's worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J'ai tiré quelques extraits caractéristiques de deux articles :

http://lebonusage.over-blog.com/article-w-derniere-lettre-entree-dans-l-alphabet-fran-ais-100230347.html

et

http://www.cosmovisions.com/lettre-W.htm

La lettre w (double-v) est propre aux langues du Nord et n'est usitée en français que dans les mots empruntés à ces langues avec leur orthographe. 
C'est une lettre récente et d'invention germanique; on a hésité pendant un temps entre w et gu pour rendre le même son. On l'a d'ailleurs introduit même dans des mots qui ne l'appelaient pas, comme Ewangelium pour Evangelium. Dans certains manuscrits, surtout du bas Moyen âge, on l'emploie aussi bien pour désigner le groupe [vu] (wlt, par ex.), que pour marquer la consonne [w]. D'autre part, ce dernier son est assez souvent désigné par deux u ou deux v qui restent séparés.

Bien que la lettre W eût été utilisée depuis le XVIIe siècle, le W n’était pas encore considéré comme lettre à part entière dans le Dictionnaire de l’Académie française de 1935.

Le W est « la dernière venue » (dans l'alphabet français) selon Grevisse et Goosse, Bon Usage, 13e édition, 1993, § 84, p. 85.

En 1878, les mots en W- furent isolés, mais la lettre était définie ainsi : lettre consonne qui appartient à l’alphabet de plusieurs peuples du Nord et qu’on emploie en français pour écrire un certain nombre de mots empruntés aux langues de ces peuples, mais sans en faire une lettre de plus dans notre alphabet.

Le dictionnaire Le Robert (1964) est le premier à déclarer que « W est la 23e lettre de l’alphabet. » (Bon Usage, ibid.).

En bref (citant @LPH)

> On ne peut donc pas conclure plus que ceci : l'emprunt date du bas Moyen Âge, il provient des langues germaniques mais pas nécessairement d'abord de l'anglais ou de l'allemand et son usage premier était la représentation de [vu] et de [w] (et la lettre n'a été considérée comme une lettre à part entière du français que très tard, Robert - 1964).

Comment: On ne peut donc pas conclure plus que ceci :  l'emprunt date du bas Moyen Âge, il provient des langues germaniques mais pas nécessairement d'abord de l'anglais ou de l'allemand et  son usage premier était la représentation de [vu] et de [w] (et la lettre n'a été considérée comme une lettre à part entière du français que très tard, Robert - 1964).